# Enabling Java assertions not working with Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, assert, assertions

I tried enabling assertions for Java 8 in Eclipse Luna by doing what most answers on here suggest, adding -ea as a VM argument in the Run config, as well as in the default VM arguments in the JRE config. Still I get the same error as before:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - 'assert' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source       level 1.4 on
>     - Syntax error on token "assert", ( expected
>     - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression
>     - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression

My program is really just a simple program to try it out:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        assert x != 0 : "Test";
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `asseration` sounds painful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I anwer my own question, since the solution was hidden in a comment until now:

Removing -ea from the default parameters, but keeping it in the run configuration solved the problem, for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Installed JREs` -> select your installed JVM -> `Edit..` -> in "Default VM arguments:" add `-ea`.

Finally make sure that your project uses same JVM in which you added `-ea` as default argument. To do that :

`right click on project` -> `Properties` -> `JavaBuildPath` -> `Libraries` here you should see `JRE system library[...]`. Make sure that in `[...]` is JVM you edited to enable assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Keep parentheses around the x != 0. That might fix your problem.

Comment: That is not the problem here (works fine for me without parenthesis).

Comment: Still not working, but it gives me a shorter error message, at least.                                                          Multiple markers at this line
 - 'assert' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source 
  level 1.4 on
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator

Comment: At least we are getting somewhere.

Comment: Ok, removing -ea from the default variables, but keeping it in the run config solved the problem, unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

in Eclipse, Right click on Project -> properties -> select java compiler-> click on java build path-> select jre ->click on edit-> Execution Environment select  J2SE-1.5(jre1.8.0_65) -> finish